# Java - Most efficient method for adding values associated with duplicate keys?

Tags: java, excel, key

I have a list with a key(non-unique) and a set of values associated with that key. A key might appear more than once in the list. For all the multiple occurrences of a particular key, I need to be able to add the corresponding associated set of values.

The way I am receiving the input is that some of the values seem to be broken down into multiple rows.

(Before answering, please bear in mind that I am receiving the input in the form of Excel Sheets and I am reading from the Excel Sheet in Java using Apache POI. So, before suggesting me to change the way the data is stored to avoid redundancy, please note that this is something out of my control as is handled by another team.)

I tried using multi-dimensional arrays, but this was a lot of pain.

So, I am looking for suggestions on a better method for implementing my list/set using a Java Collection to be able to add the values associated with duplicate keys. I am not looking for any form of code, but just suggestions for the most efficient way to implement this. If you can just name a few methods, I can take it from there.

I truly appreciate your time for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by efficient, you mean easy to use and maintain, then [`MultiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) from Apache Commons Collections is just the ticket.

Comment: I'd have to go with Guava like Jon Skeet suggested due to Apache Common Collections complete lack of support for Generics.

Comment: Fair enough, it was just the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: Multimap from Apache was much easier for me to understand based on my level of Java-proficiency as compared to Guava Multimap which slightly intimidated me upon closer look. Will see if this works. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Java_nuB @R. Bemrose is right though, in the long run you'll need generics. But Commons Collections is as good a start as anything else.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want a [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) collection from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Like a `Map`, but where you get a collection of values associated with a key instead of just one.

Have a look at the [`Multimaps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) class for common factory methods.

Comment: Multimap looks great. I will try and implement. But, if I get stuck, I may need more help. Appreciate your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

See the part about chaining